# Why am I getting null for a document.getElementById call, after $(document).ready(function() { ... }) is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a small example. I'm probably missing something basic, it's been a while since I worked with javascript.

My issue is I'm getting the error (in Chrome developer tools): `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null at Image.image1.onload (index.html:15)"`

It seems like a straight forward error. However, I believe the document should already be loaded when this is getting called because of the `$(document).ready(function(){imageA();});`. So I don't know why it can't find the element `#image_holder`.

It's a pretty small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Quiz</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var imageASelection = 1;
            /* ImageA */
            function imageA() {
                var image1 = new Image();
                image1.onload = function() {
                    document.getElementById('image_holder').src = this.src;
                }
                image1.src="images/ImageA.jpg";
                $('html, body, #map').html('\
                <map name="image-map">\
                    <area onclick="imageAOption1();" coords="827,1305,297,795" shape="rect">\
                    <area onclick="imageAOption2();" coords="1361,1307,839,800" shape="rect">\
                    <area onclick="imageAOption3();" coords="1370,792,1888,1300" shape="rect">\
                    <area onclick="imageAOption4();" coords="1895,788,2431,1305" shape="rect">\
                    <area onclick="imageANext();" coords="2431,1640,2146,1479" shape="rect">\
                </map>');
            }
            function imageAOption1() {
                imageASelection = 1;
            }
            function imageAOption2() {
                imageASelection = 2;
            }
            function imageAOption3() {
                imageASelection = 3;
            }
            function imageAOption4() {
                imageASelection = 4;
            }
            function imageANext() {
                imageB();
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                imageA();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="image_holder" usemap="#image-map">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

And if you're wondering what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to load an image in the background. I will have multiple images, but I don't want to see a flicker. So I'm trying to load the image in the background. If I'm approaching this wrong, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
 $('html, body, #map').html('\
    <map name="image-map">\
       <area onclick="imageAOption1();" coords="827,1305,297,795" shape="rect">\
       <area onclick="imageAOption2();" coords="1361,1307,839,800" shape="rect">\
       <area onclick="imageAOption3();" coords="1370,792,1888,1300" shape="rect">\
       <area onclick="imageAOption4();" coords="1895,788,2431,1305" shape="rect">\
       <area onclick="imageANext();" coords="2431,1640,2146,1479" shape="rect">\
    </map>');
```

you're overriding the entire body, replacing your image; by the time the image is loaded, it is not in the document.

Perhaps you wanted to replace `#map`rather than the entire body ?

then you should look it up by `$('#map')`, or `$('html body #map')` without the commas.